# Npm failure for the ionic project creation

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-react

ionic start my-app tabs --capacitor

Pick a framework!

Please select the JavaScript framework to use for your new app. To bypass this prompt next time, supply a value for the
--type option.

? Framework: React
√ Preparing directory .\my-app in 2.24ms
√ Downloading and extracting tabs starter in 325.63ms

> ionic integrations enable capacitor --quiet -- my-app io.ionic.starter
> npm.cmd i --save -E @capacitor/core
> npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
> npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! While resolving: ionic-app-base@0.1.0
> npm ERR! Found: typescript@4.1.3
> npm ERR! node_modules/typescript
> npm ERR!   typescript@"4.1.3" from the root project
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
> npm ERR! peerOptional typescript@"^3.2.1" from react-scripts@4.0.1
> npm ERR! node_modules/react-scripts
> npm ERR!   react-scripts@"4.0.1" from the root project
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
> npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
> npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! See C:\Users\sowmyans\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\sowmyans\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-02-03T21_23_15_246Z-debug.log
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess npm.

```
    npm.cmd i --save -E @capacitor/core exited with exit code 1.
```

## npm resolution error report

2021-02-03T20:47:47.168Z

Found: typescript@4.1.3
node_modules/typescript
typescript@"4.1.3" from the root project

Could not resolve dependency:
peerOptional typescript@"^3.2.1" from react-scripts@4.0.1
node_modules/react-scripts
react-scripts@"4.0.1" from the root project

Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

Raw JSON explanation object:

{
"code": "ERESOLVE",
"current": {
"name": "typescript",
"version": "4.1.3",
"location": "node_modules/typescript",
"dependents": [
{
"type": "prod",
"name": "typescript",
"spec": "4.1.3",
"from": {
"location": "C:\Users\[user]\\source\repos\ionic\my-app"
}
}
]
},
"edge": {
"type": "peerOptional",
"name": "typescript",
"spec": "^3.2.1",
"error": "INVALID",
"from": {
"name": "react-scripts",
"version": "4.0.1",
"location": "node_modules/react-scripts",
"dependents": [
{
"type": "prod",
"name": "react-scripts",
"spec": "4.0.1",
"from": {
"location": "C:\Users\[user]\source\repos\ionic\my-app
}
}
]
}
},
"peerConflict": null,
"strictPeerDeps": false,
"force": false
}

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem in the past. I could only resolve it by manually deleting the dependencies that he was about one by one from the global node_modules folder. Whenever, I would delete one package, it would tell me there is a conflict in another package as well which I kept on deleting and at the end I got the application up and running.